# Javascript - is image rgb or rgba

Tags: javascript, image, textures, webgl, rgb

I'm rewriting my opengl program from c++ to webgl/js.

In my c++ code I ust stb_image to parse images from file. As one of the options, I could get the depth of an image, so I always know is it RGB or RGBA. This allowed me to load textures with the required parameters (took from learnopengl.com):

```
int width, height, nrComponents;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
if (data)
{
    GLenum format;
    if (nrComponents == 1)
        format = GL_RED;
    else if (nrComponents == 3)
        format = GL_RGB;
    else if (nrComponents == 4)
        format = GL_RGBA;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Is there some method in js, that can return the nrComponents for an image?

For example, if I use that code:

```
function LoadTexture2D(filename)
{
    var texID;
        texID = gl.createTexture();
        img = new Image();
        img.getColorModel
        img.onload = function () { handleTextureLoaded(img, texID)};
        img.src = filename;

    }

    function handleTextureLoaded(image, texture) {
        var format = 0;
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        if (image.getDepth()==3)
        format = gl.RGB;
        if (image.getDepth()==4)
        format = gl.RGBA;
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, format,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    }
```

Is there something like `getDepth()`; ?

Comment: To extract pixels/channels of an image you need to render it onto a `canvas` and then [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData). At that point you always deal with RGBA data.

Comment: Hi!

What do you mean "at that point"?

Comment: With that I mean, that there is no such thing as `Image.gimmetheRawData()` or so. You need to go through a canvas to get to the pixels. And although I don't know wether the browser itself distinguishes between RGB and RGBA images, when you get the RAW data from the canvas, it will always be RGBA.

Comment: thank you for help!

Comment: @Thomas There are other methods of reading pixels, such as [`readPixels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels)